# How can I write a list comprehension to create a list of sets?

Tags: python, set, list-comprehension

I tried to create a list of sets `[set([0]), set([1]), set([2]),..]` using

```
>>> [set(i) for i in range(9)]
```

but it did not come out well

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How to create that list with a list comprehension? Is it possible?

Comment: `set(i)` is not like `set([0])`. Can you see the difference?

Comment: can i ask why you are trying to create list of set having one element, just for practicing list comprehension or you ve use case?

Comment: @yopy: I'm using this to build the subtrees for an implementation of  [Kruskal's minimal spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). The initialization creates n subtrees (the sets) containing one element. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create `[set([0]), set([1]), set([2]),..]` with a list comprehension you would use:

```
>>> [{i} for i in range(5)] 
[set([0]), set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([4])]
```

Unless you are using any version of Python prior to version 2.7, then use:

```
>>> [set((i,)) for i in range(5)]
[set([0]), set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([4])]
```

However, it seems kind of silly that you are creating a list of sets where each set is a single integer of increasing sequence. Whatever you are trying to accomplish might be better done a different way, please consult [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and make sure you are not falling into this.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there may be a better way to store your data, or perform the logic you are trying to perform.

**NOTE:**

Originally I wrote `[set([i]) for i in range(5)]` But after timing the different options, I realized that converting the integer into a single-item list is more wasteful than converting it to a tuple, so I changed my answer, and subsequently changed it again to use the set literal , timing below:

```
>python -mtimeit "[{i} for i in range(5)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.853 usec per loop

>python -mtimeit "[set((i,)) for i in range(5)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 usec per loop

>python -mtimeit "[set([i]) for i in range(5)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 usec per loop
```

Comment: Unless the OP is using a very old Python, `[{i} for i in range(5)]` should also work.

Comment: `[{i} for i in range(5)]` I'll take that

Comment: Thanks for the advice concerning the XY Problem